# How do I prevent Motion from using up the entire SD card?

Tags: webcam

I have a webcam running with Motion.

It's all working fine, however, after a while it stops working.

This appears to be because it is filling up the `/tmp/motion` directory with jpegs. (Clearing out this directory and then restarting motion always brings it back up.)

I've set up a cron job to to delete old jpegs, but that feels like tackling the symptom and not the source of the problem, so I was wondering if there is a setting for it built into Motion.

Is there a way to prevent Motion from using up more than a set amount of disk space for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also look at using `streamer` to send the images to a server or add a NAS mount point to save the images to.

The following link is a thread where a guy outlines how he achieved what I had suggested; using streamer to send the camera images to an external server. [Send images to external server using streamer](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=34766&p=302719&hilit=webcams#p302719)

Comment: Please elaborate on the link. It is not good style to give *link answers.*

Comment: "The following link is a thread where a guy describes how he used streamer" - That pretty much covers it. The guy outlines how achieved what I had suggested using `streamer` to send the camera images to an external server.

Comment: The issue with that, and the reason why it is discouraged is because *links can change.* Just add your comment to your answer, and it will be *far* better. In fact, I will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would think about creating **new user** and setting him some **quota**, eg. 2gb. This user will run motion in users **specific directory** but he could not use more than specific amount of disk space. The only think left to do would be to run some *erase* script after motion reach the size limit. It's not the direct solution, but as I can read the **motion** documentation there is no such functionality. The only think you can set up about size is the maximum length of the movie.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another partition (ext4 filesystem) on the SD card specifically for that purpose, and mount it to /tmp/motion, or create symlink from /tmp/motion to the actual mount point.